# Create points (shapefile) with ogr2og from an attribute table

Tags: ogr2ogr

I have a csv file containing lon,lat coordinates. I want to create a vector layer (points with the lon/lat coordinates) using ogr2ogr.

I did the following:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" "vector.shp" "coords.csv" -oo X_POSSIBLE_NAMES=lon* -oo Y_POSSIBLE_NAMES=lat* -a_srs EPSG:4326 -nlt POINT -skipfailures
```

The result is a shapefile with no geometry values. Do I have to define anything else in the above command?

A sample of the coords.csv is as following:

```
Lon_rounde  Lat_rounde  ISO3    Year    GNFR_Secto  SourceType  CH4
-17.05  32.675  PRT 2015    A   A   57.69167458
```

I also tried to use the whole name of lon, lat (with the same result) :

```
> ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" "vector.shp" "coords.csv" -oo
> X_POSSIBLE_NAMES= Lon_rounde -oo Y_POSSIBLE_NAMES=Lat_rounde -a_srs
> EPSG:4326 -nlt POINT -skipfailures
```

Comment: Add a sample of your csv file with the header line (if you have a header line) and one data line.

Comment: @user30184 I edited my question.

Comment: What is your GDAL version (`ogrinfo --version`)?

Comment: I use GDAL 2.1.0dev with GEOS support

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by using GDAL v2.4 (with v2.1 was not working)

Comment: I suppose that the part that was not working was just the use of POSSIBLE_NAMES open option that was new to 2.1 release version  https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/csv.html. Reading through the .VRT file should have worked.